# Typed immutable objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, reactjs-flux, immutable.js

I am trying organize data types in React Flux-like application. All my data objects are immutable, for collections I am using immutable.js, which is perfect library for that. But for typed objects i use my own classes. I don't think it is the best solution, but i need to somehow handle default values, internal consistency, validations of data, add methods to that objects etc.

- Is there some library available for that purpose?
- Do you use immutable.js collections also for that kind of objects? So you handle consistency of data, validations and other functionality somewhere else?
- Or do you use plain classes for that?
- Do you think that is good idea to have typed objects in React/Flux based application?

Here is example of what kind of objects i mean and simple example how I use it.

```
class Event extends MyImmutableLib {
     constructor(plain) {
          this.start = plain.start;
          this.end = plain.end;
          this.name = plain.name || "unnamed event"; // some default value
          this.attendants = plain.attendants || [];
          this.valid = plain.start < plain.end; // simple check of validity, I can also throw exception if it is needed
          Object.freeze(this); // I use freeze to be sure I don't accidentally change the object
     }
     getDuration() {
          return this.end - plain.start; // methods are sometimes useful
     }
     addAttendant(newPerson) { 
          return this.set("attendants", this.attendants.concat([newPerson])) //immutable edit, so I return new object
     }
}

var someEvent = new Event({start: new Date("2015-02-29"), end: new Date("2012-02-30")}) //
var jsMeetup =  someEvent.set("name", "9th Js Meetup, Brno")
var jsMeetup = jsMeetup.addAttendant("Joe");

console.log(jsMeetup.name, jsMeetup.getDuration())
```

The best would be some library with:

- Typed objects - so I would have my data better organized.
- Default values
- Validations
- Methods
- Immutability specific functions

Comment: Could it be that you are looking for records? http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. I will try it tomorrow if it fits my needs. Do you know any project (real world or demo) where it is used?

Comment: immutable.js? People at Facebook use it for various projects. And of course, as you said yourself, it works really well with React, so I'm sure there are other React developers who use it.

Comment: Voting to close because it's asking for offsite resources, overly broad, primarily opinion based, and asking multiple questions in a single question.  These are all good questions, but this isn't on-topic on StackOverflow.